# Changing column names then converting all negative values to NA

Tags: r, names

Hi I am trying to change all my column names to different names and then convert all my column vectors which hold negative values to NA. I got the second part right but for some reason I am unable to properly change the column names to different names. This is my code; note that mscr is the csv with the column names I wish to change; I just rename it to df2. Thank you for your time and help.

```
df2 <- mscr %>%
  rename(
    caseid = R0000100,
    children2000 = R6389600
    )

df2 <- mscr
df2[df2 < 0] <- NA
```

Comment: What is the issue with the first part

Comment: It changes the name, but not the csv; mscr is a csv file.

Comment: You need to read the data with `read.csv`

Comment: right, so I read the mscr.csv file first, then put those changes, however, when I View(mscr), none of my changes are visible.

Comment: You saved the changes into df2 not mscr

Comment: Are you saying that the `%>% rename(.)` is changing the in-memory data but you want it to make the changes to a file as well? Or is it that you `rename(.)` the column names, store the updated data into `df2`, and then immediately overwrite this `df2` with the original data and wonder why the names have reverted?

Comment: Yes, sorry, so I am able to see the changes I made by switching the cells from negative to NA but I am unable to see the column name changes. It keeps it the same from before.

Comment: `rename` does not work in *side-effect*, meaning the original data (to the left of `%>%`) is unchanged. `mscr %>% rename(.)` will ***never*** change `msvr` unless you reassign back into it, ala `mscr <- mscr %>% rename(.)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, r2evans, your suggested helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding, but I think what you're doing is renaming the columns (successfully), and then over-writing the newly-renamed data with the original. That is,

```r
df2 <- mscr %>% rename(...)
```

is correct, and the names should then be changed. The moment you then do

```r
df2 <- msvr
```

before you then replace non-positive values, you revert any changes you made.

`rename` (and just about every "verb" function in `dplyr` and many in R) operates solely in a *functional* manner, which means the input data is completely unchanged. If it were changed in-place, this would be ["side effect"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), and antithetic to the "normal/idiomatic way" to do things in R.

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df2 <- mscr %>%
  rename(
    caseid = R0000100,
    children2000 = R6389600
  ) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ if_else(. < 0, .[NA], .)))
```

One would normally want to use *just* `NA`, but since `NA` is technically a `logical` class, and I'm inferring that your data is `numeric` or `integer`, we need to get the right class. One option is to do this step individually for `numeric` and then `integer` columns, for which we would use `NA_real_` and `NA_integer_`, respectively. However, `.[NA]` in this case will give the `NA` classed the same as the original column data.

Comment: I must admit, @IceCreamToucan, that seems rather obscure ... is that intentionally obfuscating (perhaps jokingly), or was it necessary at some point?

Comment: `.[NA]` has the added benefit of working on `character` and `POSIXt`, no less.

Comment: I think plenty of R users tend to be comfortable with `base::ifelse`'s class-promiscuity, and we're finding all sorts of "fun" with `dplyr::if_else` and `data.table::fifelse` actually enforcing class-consistency. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯